# jquery sound player without going through flash

Tags: jquery

I don't understand what Dusan Jovanovic means when he refers to host_element in his documentation about [DBJ-SOUND](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.dbj_sound.js.txt).

Q: What do I put into:

```
$.dbj_sound.play( host_element )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this:

```
* return sound file url from host element
* host must be valid html element with attribute href present
* $.dbj_sound.url( host_element )
```

it seems the host_element is an anchor tag with something like `href="path/to-your-sound.wav"`.

Comment: This worked:
var host_element = $('a#whistle');
<a id="whistle" href="Referee.wav">